# upper to lower case in c++

Tags: c++, ascii, c-strings, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to transform a string of characters from lower to upper case and the other way round on c++. All this without using libraries, and using ascii code instead.
My problem is I don't know how to get the ascii code of a character, change it, and then transform it to character again. I only know how to do it by printing it, but I need to do this transformation on the memory.
How can I do this?

This is what I've tried:

```
char* invertirCase(char* str){
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i;
    int valor;
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        valor = (int)str[i];
        if (valor >= 65 && valor <= 90) {
            valor = valor + 32;
            str[i] = (char)valor;
        }
        else if (valor >= 97 && valor <= 122) {
            valor = valor - 32;
            str[i] = (char)valor;
        }
    }
    
    return str;
}
```

Comment: *All this without using libraries* -- You call `strlen()` in your code.  That is a library function.

Comment: The code you have looks like it would do the job.  Did you have an actual question?

Comment: It does do the job.  I just ran it.  I don't understand either.

Comment: Just for fun, you can do `str[i] ^= 0b00100000`, and combine both your if-statements. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/b3js9GzYK (I also removed `strlen`, since you said no library functions).

Comment: The real question is why do teachers still think it’s the 70s? What, exactly is the goal of not allowing toupper? Something which every modern language is going to provide?

Comment: @Taekahn - to make sure C programmers actually know whats going on, otherwise it gets treating like magic. Do they get acsii encoding for example.

Comment: @pm100 -- and that's why so many programmers think that the world of character encodings begins and ends with ASCII -- they've been taught to work with the details of ASCII, but haven't been taught the abstraction.

Comment: @PeteBecker it will be interesting to see what mathematical formula they come up with to convert `ß` to upper case.

Answer (score 2):

Using the cast operator in your program is redundent.

Also the condition in the for loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
            ^^^^^^^^
```

will look more correctly in general if to write

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ^^^^^^^^
```

because `str[len]` yields the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string that you are not going to change in any case.

And it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `65`.

Without using standard functions the function can be defined the following way

```
char * invertirCase( char *s ) 
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p != '\0'; ++p ) 
    {
        if ( 'A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z' ) 
        {
            *p += 'a' - 'A';
        }
        else if ( 'a' <= *p && *p <= 'z' ) 
        {
            *p -= 'a' - 'A';
        }
    }
    
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you prefer `'\0'` to plain `0`?

Comment: @MarkRansom To underline that in the expression there are used objects of the type char.